# Loading specific modules inside sub packages in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a the below directory structure in my project

```
-serviceProvider
   __init__.py
   api.py
   -service1
       __init__.py
       service.py
       api.py
   -service2
       __init__.py
       service.py
       api.py
   -service3
       __init__.py
       service.py
       api.py
   -service4
       __init__.py
       service.py
       api.py
```

The user will only import the serviceProvider/api.py file and access the rest of the functionalities provided by the services.

I am planning to use a registry mechanism, whereby once the user imports the serviceProvider package, all service packages are also loaded and they register to the provider.

My question is what is the mechanism i should use to load all the service.py files inside all the sub-packages once the main serviceProvider is loaded??

One solution i found online is to use the pkgutil.

https://michaelheap.com/python-dynamically-load-all-modules-in-a-folder/

This solution mandates the given code-snipet to be specified in each of the sub package init.py files.. is there some other mechanism i can use??

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this without using any mechanism other than the modules **init**.py files.

You can import the different functions or classes you want in the submodules **init**.py, and then import those from the parent module. For example, in `service1.__init__.py`, you can import the different python files you've written. This would look like:

```
from service1 import service, api
```

This will allow you to import them in the `serviceProvider.__init__.py`, which would look like (including all services)

```
from service1 import service as service1, api as api1
from service2 import service as service2, api as api2
from service3 import service as service3, api as api3
from service4 import service as service4, api as api4
```

then in `serviceProvider.api` you can import those named imports by calling there new names, like so:

```
from serviceProvider import service1, api1, service2, api2
```

You'll want to give them unique names so you can call them without confusion. This will also import the python file with all its functions, so you can say in your code

```
service2.some_function(arguments)
```

you can also just import specific functions or objects by specifying what you want to import in the `serviceProvider.__init__.py`:

```
from service1.service import my_function
from service1.api import ApiClass as ApiClass1
from service2 import service as service2, api as api2
from service3 import service as service3, api as api3
from service4 import service as service4, api as api4
```

Comment: But this would be a brute force method.. i dont want users to do this in the __init__.py files.. the users should plug their code into the services folder and the service provider should automatically recognise and load it... with this solution that is not possible...